# Yosemite folder icon didn't update?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I joined the beta program and downloaded the Yosemite beta a couple of months ago. I am up to date with all updates.

For some reason, the folder icon for my "Books" folder didn't update to the Yosemite folder icon. All my other icons are fine, it's just this one. Anyone know how I can fix this? I already tried deleting the cache at ~/Library/Cache and /Library/Cache.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Books” is not a Mac OS X standard home folder sub-folder, at least as of Mavericks. (I don't have Yosemite on hand to test with.) Some application you use has created that folder and given it a custom icon.

(The standard subfolders' icons are not written into them as custom icons; rather, they are recognized by their name and location and only *displayed* with the corresponding icon. That's why they automatically match the folder icons for whatever OS version you are running. Custom icons can't do that.)

If you want the icon to look like a Yosemite folder icon, then **Get Info** on the folder, click on the icon at the top, and press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key. This will give it the standard blank folder appearance.

If you want a Yosemite-styled Books icon, then you'll have to wait for whichever application decided there should be a Books folder to be updated to Yosemite style (and you might have to delete the icon, *not* delete the icon, or do something more complex to prod the application into resetting the icon, depending on how exactly it was programmed).